# ScrollView isn`t working. What should I do?

Tags: java, android, scrollview

How can I scroll in my Android app?

I already tried Scrollview but it doesn`t work.

So this is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.myapplication2;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.icu.text.IDNA;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static com.example.myapplication2.R.id.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment){
        if(fragment!=null){
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(fragment_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.bottomnav);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(fragment_container, new Home_Screen()).commit();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
            case kontakt:
                break;

            case Termine:
                fragment = new TermineFragment();
                break;

            case wilkommen:
                fragment = new Home_Screen();
                break;              
        }

        return loadFragment(fragment);
    }
}
```

And this is my XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:background="@color/darkgrey">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Termine"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            ></TextView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="173dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            >

        <Button
                android:text="Mehr infos"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="170dp"
                />

        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:background="@color/maincolor"

                >
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:text="HPI - 29.06.19"
                  android:textSize="24dp"
                />

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:text="Sitzung: H-E.51"
                  android:textSize="16dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

                />
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:text="Juni22, 2019"
                  android:textSize="16dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
                />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="173dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

                />

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:text="HPI - 13.07.19"
                  android:textSize="24dp"
                />

        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:text="Sitzung: H-E.51"
                  android:textSize="16dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

                />
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="@color/white"
                  android:text="July13, 2019"
                  android:textSize="16dp"
                  android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                  android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                  android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"

                />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

What should I do? I want these Cardviews in my Scrollview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your XML layout code with the below. Also, be notified, there seems to be an awkward amount of topMargin between your two cards, not sure if that's intended or not but as of now, there is huge gap between your two cards :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="@color/darkgrey">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Termine"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="173dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            >

            <Button
                android:text="Mehr infos"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="170dp" />


            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/maincolor">

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="HPI - 29.06.19"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Sitzung: H-E.51"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Juni22, 2019"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="270dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="173dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            >

            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"

                />

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="HPI - 13.07.19"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                />

            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Sitzung: H-E.51"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"

                />
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="July13, 2019"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"

                />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nice man , thank you very much for your Comment ... I really thought there weren no more hope in my App ... But thank You I made it ... Thank You really I appreciate it very much ....

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView in place of RelativeLayout. Add a LinearLayout with vertical orientation before the first TextView and close the LinearLayout after the CardView.